# How to check current time with event time in android?

Tags: android

From the web portal am assigning the event to calendar date. I want to create the alarm notification, when the event time matches with the current mobile time. For this situation i have written the following code.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String time = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
    if(time==cts1.start)
    {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Here cts1.start is an event time. But this logic will check the time for every second. Is there any better way is available to achieve the same logic. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of manually checking the time, why don't you set the alarm to the event time in millisecond directly? `alarmManager.`[`set`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)`(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cts1.start, pendingIntent);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [getTimeInMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()) method on the `Calendar`. It will return Unix milliseconds since 1970, so is more precise, also longs are somewhat easier to work with (add, subtract) than date strings.